# Why setTimeout works on Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, settimeout, webapi

I am hearing that `setTimeout()`, the Web API is not included in JavaScript quite often. So, if it is only Web API it is natural to think as it won't work anywhere except in the browser. So, why `setTimeout` is working in my terminal when I just run a plain old JS file with the `node ${filename}` command?

Comment: Check https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/#when-i-say-so-execution-settimeout

Comment: Thanks you! So it is Node related feature and JS have nothing to do with that yes? Is the statement JS do not have `setTimeout` right?

Answer (score 4):

The browser and node.js both have a global `setTimeout` function, but the return types are different between the two.

- node.js setTimeout returns a Timeout object: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#settimeoutcallback-delay-args
- Browser setTimeout returns an integer timer id: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: So is this means that Node JS has own Callback Queue and some API to count? Cool did not know! Thanks for info!